# Change window frame color on an application basis

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, windows-8.1, themes

Although I can change the global theme of Windows, all the elements of the OS have the same color scheme. I would like the scrollbars, buttons, etc on win 8.1, to be different for different applications. In other words, something like themes applied to each application.

Comment: Up! Is there updates on this question please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Stardock WindowBlinds](http://www.stardock.com/products/windowblinds/features.asp) can do this. I personally own a copy of this program, so I can say it works. From the link:

> #### Per application skinning
>
> Choose skins for each of your application types. For example, WindowBlinds enables your word processing software to use a different skin than your design programs.

Keep in mind, however, that any application which does not use the standard Windows widgets can, at its option, ignore any theme settings that you try to apply. It doesn't even have to respect your window borders; an application can render its own if it wants to.

WindowBlinds will work for *many* applications that use native Windows widgets and/or window borders, such as Qt, SWT, ATL, .NET WinForms and WPF. There are other toolkits for drawing GUIs, however, where only the window border effects will be applied; for example, Swing, GTK, wxWidgets, Motif, etc. And then certain applications, like Firefox and Chrome, can either optionally, or by design (with no option to change it), tell Windows not to draw any borders around its windows, which means that, if it then uses non-standard widgets, your customizations would be *entirely* absent.

It's not perfect, and there's no universal solution, but this should take care of "most" applications.

Comment: thank you. i just find it convenient to identify my windows by looking a for a color. having to actually parse what i am looking at requires i look at the contents of the window and that takes more time. i dont know why the OS designers did not think of this.

Comment: "an application can render it's own if it wants to" _looks at Java_

Comment: my apologies, i cannot get this app to work on win 8.1. it says it's not installed well, tries to fix itself and nothing happens. oh well.