# Set window border color

Tags: windows

Is there a way (or tool) to set the border color of a window based on some property of that window? For example, I often find myself having two database editors open with a different connection. I would like to make on of those windows a different color to distinguish them (red = production, green = test for example). My google-fu skills didn't return anything useful.

Comment: This functionality already exists in SQL Server Management, Studio if you're using it?

Comment: unfortunately not, I am using another industry-specific product that does not offer this functionality. thats why I am looking for another way :)

Comment: Then I'm afraid I am out of answers - sorry. But an interesting question!

Comment: yeah it would be a nice little tool to have

Comment: Take a look at https://superuser.com/questions/820570/change-window-frame-color-on-an-application-basis. The application referred to in the answer there can do per-application skinning. I don't know if it can use a different color based, not on the application name, but on a more granular distinction. But if it can, it might work for your need.

Comment: thank you. I saw that answer already, however that program is much too big and i don't really want to install it (Ive played around with that already). I'm rather looking for a very small tool that's not bloating up my system