# Changing color of tabs in Firefox and frames of applications in general

Tags: windows-8, colors

I would like to know **where** can I change my (nice btw) orange color of frames in Firefox under Windows 8.1.
See the two snippets. I would like to touch esp. the frame's color with label "Tento počítač".

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**To change Firefox tab color and customize**

1.Click the menu button and click Customize

2.Select **Themes** option at below and customize color whatever you wish

[image]

**Make sure you have updated firefox to latest version** by selecting Menu < Help < About Firefox and Click check for updates and see "Firefox is Upto Date"
or update to latest version

[image]

**To change applications frames in general**

```
Per application skinning

Choose skins for each of your application types. For example, WindowBlinds enables your word processing software to use a different skin than your design programs.
```

Keep in mind, however, that any application which does not use the standard Windows widgets can, at its option, ignore any theme settings that you try to apply. It doesn't even have to respect your window borders; an application can render its own if it wants

https://www.stardock.com/products/windowblinds/#features

Source:
[Change window frame color on an application basis](https://superuser.com/questions/820570/change-window-frame-color-on-an-application-basis)

Comment: My OQ was **not** about FF. I wanted to change **all** frames of **all** windows under WIn 8.1 !

Comment: **I would like to know where can I change my (nice btw) orange color of frames in Firefox under Windows 8.1**.This meant solely you wanted to change firefox frames and you did not specifically say you wanted to change windows frames under OS.The question is not clear

Comment: @EliteX - Where are the quotes?  If you don’t quote another person’s words that’s called plagiarism.